# How to open a Visualforce page using formula (Hyperlink) field dynamically from console or standard SF

Tags: visualforce, service-cloud-console, configuration

I have a visualforce page. I need to open that page in Service Cloud Console sub-tab when user is within Service Cloud Console with some required parameters and if user is not within console then the page should be open in the SF Classic.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: There's a thread on developer force forums that addresses this, I haven't tested the final "agreed" format but it'd be a good place for you to start!  https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008w2ZIAQ

Comment: How are you opening that page? Custom link, custom button, etc...?

There are a few ways to do it, depending on what your flow is. The below example is for a custom button, but you could use the same sforce.console.isInConsole() method as well depending on how you are opening the page in the first place. 

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kpcfAAA

Answer (score 1):

Thanks All!!

Below formula is working for me

```
HYPERLINK("javascript:if(typeof(srcUp)=='function'){
     srcUp('/apex/SL_MyPage?p=" & Custom__r.Id & "&d=" & Custom__c&"');}
"+" else {window.location.href='/apex/SL_MyPage?p=" & Custom__r.Id & "&d=" & Custom__c&"'}", 
"Formula Label"),"_self")
```